# Skipping callbacks on record create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model `A` with an `after_commit` callback on `create` and `update`.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :update_xyz, on: [:create, :update]
end
```

A rake task is in this use case. My rake task tries to create a number of model `A` records, but have to skip this `update_xyz` callback.

Is it possible to skip these callbacks while creating records? I would prefer not to add additional gems/plugins for this.

Comment: you have the perfect illustration of why callbacks are a huge pain in apps. Avoid them if possible and keep code in context

Answer (score 7):

If you want a way to generally have the callback run, but at specific times be able to skip it, I usually go with this pattern:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_do_something

  after_save :do_something

  private

    def do_something
      return if skip_do_something
      # do work here
    end
end
```

This way it will generally always run the `do_something` callback, but it's possible to skip by doing:

```
user = User.find 1
user.skip_do_something = true
user.save
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I found a much better solution after a bit of research

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-import/0.12.0/ActiveRecord%2FBase.import

```
users = [User.new(name: "Test1"), ....]

User.import(users)
```

Doesn't invoke callbacks or validations, and much faster when the intent is to create n number of records

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
namespace :your_namespace do
  task :your_task => :environment do
    A.skip_callback(:commit, :after, :update_xyz)
    //do everything you need
    A.set_callback(:commit, :after, :update_xyz)
  end
end
```

For more information, you can check this [link](http://thelazylog.com/skip-activerecord-callbacks/).

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a condition to your callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks) for example, like:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :update_xyz, on: [:create, :update], unless :rake_task?
end
```

and defining `rake_task?` in some place appropriate.

Comment: I would rather not add a condition since this would be a one-time rake task

Comment: If you don't want to even add this less change to the controller, then all you can do is change the rake task somehow.